# DNS TXT record "vs-f1 a mx -all"

Tags: domain-name-system, txt-record

I recently took over management of a company's DNS records.  Looking at the records, everything seems to be in order.  But there is one record I can't figure out what it is for:

```
TXT domain.com "vs-f1 a mx -all"
```

There is no documentation about this record. Googling the record just gives me loads of sites about F1 racing.

It looks similar to an SPF record, but those are in place and start `v=spf1`.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: isn't a vs-f1 a local hostname?

Comment: No - that would not be within the TXT string. It would be in the domain.com part (e.g. `TXT vs-f1 "text string"` or `TXT vs-f1.domain.com "text string"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Levenshtein Distance between `v=spf1` and `vs-f1` is 2. Symbols `-` and `=` are next to each other on many keyboards. The string `vs-f1` is also positioned at the beginning of the resource record as `v=spf1` usually is. I would say there is a high probability of someone just fat-fingering it.

Comment: also all the errors are on the right hand and they are adjacent of you ignore the left hand,.